# How to Visualize Compiler handling of a Multidimensional Array

Tags: c, gcc

Please consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int array[3][4] = {
                          {47,29,18,65},
                          {10,11,12,13},
                          {20,21,22,23}
                      };

    printf ("%d", array[1][2]);

    return 0;
}
```

I have read that compiler internally converts:

```
array[row_number][col_number] to *(*(array + row_number) + colnumber)
```

Is there any GCC option using which I can get an intermediate file which can show:

```
array[row_number][col_number] replaced with *(*(array + row_number) + colnumber)
```

(Just like: gcc -E help us analyze the preprocessor related information deeply)

Thanks.

Comment: "Is there any GCC option..." - I do not think any compiler will give you info about this sort of details.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any other way of getting this kind of information?

Comment: Debugger may show you something.... Try entering expression into the "QuickView". Many debuggers allow entering expressions to inspect.

Comment: There are several gcc debugging options, like `-fdump-rtl-all -fdump-tree-all -fdump-ipa-all`. You may also try this set (bit more verbose): `-fdump-rtl-all-all -fdump-tree-all-all -fdump-ipa-all-all`.  They will generate a lot of Internal Representation (IR) dumps after every optimization. If you know name of optimization, you can control had it changed IR comparing to previous step.